# ActionController::UrlGenerationError in RegistrationsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, many-to-many

I'm building an rails app were the user sign up via Devise.

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<% resource.build_profile %>
 <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
<%= devise_error_messages! %>

<div class="container">


     <%= f.fields_for :profile do |profile_form| %>
     <div class="field">
     <%= profile_form.label :company_name %><br />
      <%= profile_form.text_field :company_name %>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
     <%= profile_form.label :buisness_type %><br />
      <%= profile_form.text_field :buisness_type %>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
      <%= profile_form.label :contact_person %><br />
      <%= profile_form.text_field :contact_person %>
      </div>
    <% end %>

    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :contact_person_email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <% if @minimum_password_length %>
    <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
    <% end %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
  </div>
</div>
```

after sign up the user is directed to the `views/profile/show.html.erb`

after sign up rails gives me this error: `ActionController::UrlGenerationError in RegistrationsController#create`

`No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"profile", :id=>nil, :user_id=>#<User id: 14, email: "fert@fhg.is", created_at: "2016-09-10 17:46:35", updated_at: "2016-09-10 17:46:35">} missing required keys: [:id]`
this is the `views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb`

in this method in the `registrations_controller.rb` **EDITED**

```
 def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
   user_profile_path(current_user.id)
 end
```

On the `views/profile/show.html.erb` page I want the user to be able to see its profile and update it.

But after sign up rails gives me this error `undefined method 'contact_person' for nil:NilClass`

I am not sure why this is happening.

In my `views/profile/show.html.erb` I have this code to access contact_person and buisness_type.

```
<div class="row">

 <div class="container">
  <h3> Profile show page </h3>

  <p>Contact Person: <%= @profile.contact_person %></p>
  <p>Buisness Type: <%= @profile.profile.buisness_type %></p>

</div>
```

in my users.rb and profile.rb I have many_to_many relations

`profile.rb`

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

`user.rb`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
 # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

        has_one :profile
        accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
  end
```

In my `profile_controller.rb` **EDITED**

```
class ProfileController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user!

#before_action :only_current_user

def new
    #form where a user can fill put their pwn profile.

    @user = User.find(params[:user_id]) # Finnur hver er userinn sem er loggaður inn, reaching in to the url and grabbs user.
    @profile = Profile.new

end

def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @profile = @user.profile
    user_profile_path(current_user.id)
end

def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @profile = @user.build_profile(profile_params)

    #Lecture 159 User show action next :))))
    if @profile.save
        flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
        redirect_to user_profile_path(current_user.id) #fer á user/show.html.erb
    else
        render action: :new

    end

end

def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @profile = @user.profile

end

def update
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @profile = @user.profile


    if @profile.update_attributes(profile_params)
        flash[:success] = "Profile Updated!"
        redirect_to user_path(params[:user_id])
    else
        render action :edit
    end     
end


private

    def profile_params
        params.require(:profile).permit(:company_name, :address, :city, :postalcode, :permit_publisher, :permit_monitor, :contact_person, :contact_email, :phone_number, :buisness_type, :board_member, :description, :permit_duration)
    end
```

Am I missing something here? any help would be much appreciated

**EDIT accorting to Barteks answer**

when I change routes.rb to

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 devise_for :users, :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations' }
  resources :users do 
  resources :profile 
 end 

 root 'pages#index'
end
```

I get this Error now: `ActionController::UrlGenerationError in RegistrationsController#create`

`no route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"profile", :id=>nil, :user_id=>#<User id: 14, email: "fert@fhg.is", created_at: "2016-09-10 17:46:35", updated_at: "2016-09-10 17:46:35">} missing required keys: [:id]`

in this line in the registrations_controller.rb

```
def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
 user_profile_path(current_user) 
end
```

I'm even more lost now :)

Answer (score 1):

You have something wrong in controller in `show` action, because your variable `@profile` store `nil`, but firstly i recommend you to change your routes:

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations' }
  resources :users do 
    resources :profile 
  end 
  root 'pages#index'

end
```

**EDIT**

when you redirect to your profile you should include in your url `profile_id` and `user_id`,  something like this:

```
redirect_to user_profile_path(user_id,profile_id)
```

in practise it looks like 
/users/something_id/profiles/profile_id

but you using `has_one` association so try something like this:

```
redirect_to user_profile_path(user.id,user.profile.id)
```

Comment: Thank you when I change the routes rails gives me this error `ActionController::UrlGenerationError in RegistrationsController#create`         `
  `def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    user_profile_path(current_user) 
  end
  
end`

Comment: use command `rake routes` in your terminal and try adapt your all redirects to correct paths.

Comment: this is the output form `rake routes` `user_profile GET    /users/:user_id/profile/:id(.:format)      profile#show`     I've edited the path in `registrations_controller` and `profile_controller` it still gives me the error

Comment: Did you got something more information about this error ?

Comment: Yeah, I updated the question, You can see it at the top of the question, thank you

Comment: thank you but it gives me another error now: `NameError in RegistrationsController#create`  and `undefined local variable or method `user' for #<RegistrationsController:0x007fae103f3200>` in this line    `def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
   redirect_to user_profile_path(user.id,user.profile.id)
  end`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123068/discussion-between-bartek-gladys-and-dadi-hall).

Comment: I got you only example how to use it :) For you, use: `def after_sign_up_path_for(resource) redirect_to user_profile_path(current_user.id,current_user.profile.id) end`

Comment: Ok I get it :) but now I´m getting this error: `undefined method 'id' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Where you get this error, you must show all errors exactly, because i don't know your app :)

Comment: I get `NoMethodError in RegistrationsController#create`  and `undefined method 'id' for nil:NilClass` in this method                                                    `def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    redirect_to user_profile_path(current_user.id,current_user.profile.id)
  end`

Comment: It looks, you have something wrong with connections between user and profile, because `current_user.profile` return nil

Comment: Yeah...I can't figure it out..... here is a link to the github repo if you like https://github.com/DadiHall/circular1.0

Comment: Did you get this error, after user registration ? If yes, change `def after_sign_up_path_for(resource) redirect_to user_profile_path(current_user.id,current_user.profile.id) end` to this: `def after_sign_up_path_for(resource) redirect_to user_path(current_user.id) end`

Comment: When i said to change redirects i meant change redirects in `profile_controllers` :D

Comment: Ok, I´m now getting routing error, I Edited the profile_controller.rb and the registrations_controller.rb    see Edits in question

Comment: in registrations controller you have to  have  `user_path` , now you have `user_profile_path`. I recommend you watch something tutorial, to understand how it everything works.

Comment: But I want the user to go to views/profile/show.html.erb after sign up....Am I not able to do that?

Comment: You register your user in devise_create, not profile_create. So after your registration you don't have any profiles.